# How Can we clear browser local storage from a webpage

Tags: javascript

Can we clear the browser local storage from a webpage.

I can do it by going into the developer tools but my team wants that option in our webpage so that they can simply hit the clear button from the webpage and clear all the browser storage

Comment: This is not a difficult topic to research.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code line to clear localStorage:

```
localStorage.clear();
```